# How mapping from Dictionary to column

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I'd like to mapping from Dictionary that contain objects to exactly column.

Like a pivot table from row to column

How can I do that?

Example

```
    //This class I would like to Mapping by Fluent nHibernate
    public class TestDict
    {
        public virtual int ID { get; set; }
        public virtual Dictionary<string, IParameter> Dicts { get; set; }

        public TestDict()
        {
            Dicts = new Dictionary<string, IParameter>();
            Dicts.Add("parameter1", new Parameter1());
            Dicts.Add("parameter2", new Parameter2());
        }
    }
```

```
    public interface IParameter
    {
        object ParameterValue { get; }
    }

    public class Parameter1 : IParameter
    {
        public virtual object ParameterValue
        { 
            get 
            {
                return "value1";
            }
        }
    }
```

```
        
    public class Parameter2 : IParameter
    {
        public virtual object ParameterValue
        { 
            get 
            {
                return 12.3;
            }
        }
    }
```

I would like to map class TestDict that contain list of IParameter to table and result as below

```
    ID    | Parameter1     | Parameter2
    --------------------------------------
    1     | value1         | 12.3
```

How do I mapping by Fluent nHibernate?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is "dynamic component". I don't use Fluent NHibernate anymore (I believe it is obsolete), Thus to see how to map via xml or mapping by code you can check the below links and apply it to fluent:
http://ayende.com/blog/4776/support-dynamic-fields-with-nhibernate-and-net-4-0
http://notherdev.blogspot.com.tr/2012/01/mapping-by-code-dynamic-component.html